# Order posts by custom field alphabetically

Tags: wordpress, field

i heve the following loop:

```
$argsvs = array( 
                'post_type' => 'imovel-para-venda', 
                'meta_key' => 'wpcf-imovel-preco',
                'posts_per_page' => 0,
                 'oderby' => 'meta_value',
                 'order' => 'DESC'
                 );
```

$loop = new WP_Query( $argsvs );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
.....
well, the thing is that it isnt working! The meta_key 'wpfc-imovel-preco' is a custom field creating using the plugin Types. It is filled with numbers and text sometimes. Well, the code above simply doesnt sort anything :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have `oderby` instead of `orderby` - you missed the `r` in there.

I tested your code and it's otherwise working. There is only one thing to keep in mind though - number meta values will be ordered separately from string meta values, here is an example:

I have 5 pages with the following values for their custom fields: `abc`, `acb`, `dcb`, `3`, `5`. When I order them in ascending fashion, they are ordered as follows:

1. `3`
2. `5`
3. `abc`
4. `acb`
5. `dcb`

If you switch back to descending, you get:

1. `dcb`
2. `acb`
3. `abc`
4. `5`
5. `3`

Comment: i am truthfully embarassed about this.

Comment: the values are like: 100.000.00 and 120.000,00..... but 1.200.000,00 apeears before 100.000,00    , any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is that a price field? What I would suggest would be to have a second custom field that is not formatted, but holds the same number(padded with 0's), So for instance `120.000,00` would become `0012000000`(considering that the largest number that you will have will be `11.111.111,11`, or a 10 number one).